# How to prevent the values applied by default

Tags: html, forms, css

I have added the demo as you can see  below

2  `options` values `usa` and `asia` applied by default.

Firstly I needed to add placeholder to both the columns by default.

And placeholder should be different for each the tags how can I achieve this?

```js
$('#countries').scombobox({
  fullMatch: true
});

$('#continents').scombobox({
  fullMatch: true,
  highlight: false
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 23px 0 0 0;
  font-family: Arial, 'sans-serif';
  font-size: 90%;
  color: #333;
  background: #FAFAFA;
}
.scombobox {
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px;
}
.scombobox select {
  display: none;
}
.scombobox-display {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.scombobox-display:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px #CCC;
  outline: none;
}
.scombobox-display:disabled {
  background: #F0F0F0;
}
.scombobox-display.scombobox-invalid {
  background: #FFCCD4;
}
.scombobox-display-div {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.scombobox-display-div-holder {
  padding: 2px;
}
.scombobox-display-div-item {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  margin: 2px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 150px;
  padding: 4px 18px 4px 8px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: default;
  background: #F8F8F8;
  display: none;
}
.scombobox-display-div-item-text {
  max-width: 140px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.scombobox-display-div-item-remove {
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px;
  top: 2px;
  background: #A0A0A0;
  border-radius: 100px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 90%;
  padding: 1px 3px 0px;
}
.scombobox-display-div-item-remove:hover {
  background: #408CBE;
}
.scombobox-display-div-item-remove:active {
  background: #3075A3;
}
.scombobox-list {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 400px;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 300%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-top: none;
  /* instead of margin-top: -1px */
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px #CCC;
  z-index: 10;
}
.scombobox-list p {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}
.scombobox-list p input[type="checkbox"] {
  margin-right: 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.scombobox-list p:hover,
.scombobox-list p.scombobox-hovered {
  background-color: #E9EFFC;
}
.scombobox-list p.scombobox-separator {
  height: 2px;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: default;
  background: #EEE;
}
.scombobox-list p.scombobox-header {
  cursor: default;
  background: #EEE;
}
.scombobox-dropdown-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 100%;
}
.scombobox-dropdown-arrow:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
.scombobox-dropdown-background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
  border-left: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.scombobox-dropdown-background-invalid {
  border-left: 1px solid #CCC;
}
.scombobox-marker {
  background: #958FFF;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 0 2px;
  margin: 0 2px;
}
.scombobox input[type="checkbox"] {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.scombobox-disabled .scombobox-dropdown-background,
.scombobox-disabled .scombobox-dropdown-arrow {
  display: none;
}
.scombobox-disabled .scombobox-display-div {
  background: #F8F8F8;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='//cdn.rawgit.com/vijaykumarcmeseo/250f949a8de865b38e7e34bd9101e6f2/raw/670276916b77a4162e983e72aa2226cb645a6315/v.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='//cdn.rawgit.com/vijaykumarcmeseo/a9c7f54e83a228e54212c2c78a8b3422/raw/de75136be3a9beb9e4ab1538fd765e79acc58e00/lz.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<select id="countries">
  <option value="1"></option>
  <option value="2">india</option>
</select>
<select id="continents">
  <option value="1"></option>
  <option value="2">northamerica</option>
</select>
```

Comment: add the first option as `default`

Comment: you want to placeholder like select country or select continents?

Comment: @ankit can you try once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `option` with `value="0"` and  `selected`

To hide the default value, given this is a jquery plugin, you need to use this:

```
.scombobox-display:focus + .scombobox-list p:first-of-type span {
  display: none
}
```

---

```js
$('#countries').scombobox({
  fullMatch: true
});
$('#continents').scombobox({
  fullMatch: true,
  highlight: false
});
```

```css
.scombobox-display:focus + .scombobox-list p:first-of-type span {
  display: none
}
body {
  padding: 23px 0 0 0;
  font-family: Arial, 'sans-serif';
  font-size: 90%;
  color: #333;
  background: #FAFAFA;
}
.scombobox {
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px;
}
.scombobox select {
  display: none;
}
.scombobox-display {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.scombobox-display:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px #CCC;
  outline: none;
}
.scombobox-display:disabled {
  background: #F0F0F0;
}
.scombobox-display.scombobox-invalid {
  background: #FFCCD4;
}
.scombobox-display-div {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.scombobox-display-div-holder {
  padding: 2px;
}
.scombobox-display-div-item {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  margin: 2px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 150px;
  padding: 4px 18px 4px 8px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: default;
  background: #F8F8F8;
  display: none;
}
.scombobox-display-div-item-text {
  max-width: 140px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.scombobox-display-div-item-remove {
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px;
  top: 2px;
  background: #A0A0A0;
  border-radius: 100px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 90%;
  padding: 1px 3px 0px;
}
.scombobox-display-div-item-remove:hover {
  background: #408CBE;
}
.scombobox-display-div-item-remove:active {
  background: #3075A3;
}
.scombobox-list {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 400px;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 300%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-top: none;
  /* instead of margin-top: -1px */
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px #CCC;
  z-index: 10;
}
.scombobox-list p {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}
.scombobox-list p input[type="checkbox"] {
  margin-right: 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.scombobox-list p:hover,
.scombobox-list p.scombobox-hovered {
  background-color: #E9EFFC;
}
.scombobox-list p.scombobox-separator {
  height: 2px;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: default;
  background: #EEE;
}
.scombobox-list p.scombobox-header {
  cursor: default;
  background: #EEE;
}
.scombobox-dropdown-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 100%;
}
.scombobox-dropdown-arrow:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
.scombobox-dropdown-background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
  border-left: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.scombobox-dropdown-background-invalid {
  border-left: 1px solid #CCC;
}
.scombobox-marker {
  background: #958FFF;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 0 2px;
  margin: 0 2px;
}
.scombobox input[type="checkbox"] {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.scombobox-disabled .scombobox-dropdown-background,
.scombobox-disabled .scombobox-dropdown-arrow {
  display: none;
}
.scombobox-disabled .scombobox-display-div {
  background: #F8F8F8;
  cursor: default;
}
i
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='//cdn.rawgit.com/vijaykumarcmeseo/250f949a8de865b38e7e34bd9101e6f2/raw/670276916b77a4162e983e72aa2226cb645a6315/v.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='//cdn.rawgit.com/vijaykumarcmeseo/a9c7f54e83a228e54212c2c78a8b3422/raw/de75136be3a9beb9e4ab1538fd765e79acc58e00/lz.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<select id="countries">
  <option value="0" selected>Choose..</option>
  <option value="1">usa</option>
  <option value="2">india</option>
</select>
<select id="continents">
  <option value="0" selected>Choose..</option>
  <option value="1">asia</option>
  <option value="2">northamerica</option>
</select>
```

Comment: but i need to add placeholder

Comment: can you explain better that? like my updated answer now?

Comment: you want a placeholder like a title above the selects?

Comment: I mean i want to increase the size of first value

Comment: it worked @dippas but how can i increase the size of first value i mean placeholder as you said remaining values sizes should be same but i want to increase the first value size.

Comment: can you draw a picture? it is really unclear now, the selects are way wider

Comment: The choose value is appearing down again if we wont need to appear the choose value again what we should do last doubt this is from me

Comment: I have seen but the when we select choose value i mean when we click it it is showing in down that should disappear...... it should be applied default and it should not appear on bottom

Comment: thats because you are using a jQuery plugin and you will need some other changes, if was a simples select without plugin a `display: none` would work

Comment: ok dippas your work is appreciable. But if we add display:none; entire value will disapper and by default it wont shows any value

Comment: yeah it worked but where did u modified in css or html at last where did u edited the piece of code  i wan't to know

Comment: yeah but can u mention in comments in would be easy to understand

Comment: Really?? I highlighted the CSS you need it in my answer above the full code, can't you see ??????

Comment: its ok cool it worked thats what i want but for understanding purpose i asked cool your work is appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

```
<select id="countries">
    <option style="font-size:20px;display:none;">Select a country</option>
    <option value="1">usa</option>
    <option value="2">india</option>
</select>

<select id="continents">
    <option style="font-size:20px;display:none;" value="">Select a continent</option>
    <option value="1">asia</option>
    <option value="2">northamerica</option>
</select>
```

Comment: how can i add placeholder

Comment: What exactly do you mean by placeholder?

Comment: just search your city..... you are added correctly but i want to increase the size of place holder only

Comment: Ok, but where should "search your city" appear? Maybe post a basic screenshot of what you want this to look like?

Comment: I added a way to hide the default option from being displayed again in the dropdown.

Comment: let me check @pmahomme

Comment: It is removed but by default also removed my aim is to achieve select a country by default and after that it should not appear in drop down value thats my problem